# firefox does not accept @font-family declaration

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I'm having trouble, specifically with Firefox, in accepting a particular @font-face.

Here's a snippet of what I did:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cursive";
  src: url(./MTCORSVA.TTF) format("truetype");
}

.cursivefont {
  font-family: "Cursive", Verdana, Tahoma;
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Impact";
  src: url(./impact.ttf) format("truetype");
}

.impactfont16 {
  font-family: "Impact", Verdana, Tahoma;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "overrun";
  src: url(./AMBROSIA.TTF) format("truetype");
}

.ambrofont {
  font-family: "overrun";
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class=cursivefont>Join the Fight for Gunder’s Bight!</span>
<span class=impactfont16>E F</span>
<span class=ambrofont>UNCLE GLUSSOG'S TALENT PARADE</span>
```

In Windows IE (Edge) and Android Opera and Android native browser all three work.
In Windows Firefox and Chrome, and Android Firefox only the impactfont and cursivefont work, and a default font is used for ambrofont. Though, occasionally and inconsistently, Windows Firefox shows the correct font, but at the next refresh it doesn't.

I've tried cache clearance, reboot and start again etc.

Comment: Are there any errors/messages in the developer console? I wonder whether the `--debug` or `--debugger` flag in Firefox would be helpful (assuming there are debug level messages you can see there that are not exposed on the console).

Comment: Thanks, halfer, I'll try that when I get a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget double quotes around your name class ?

```
<span class=cursivefont>Join the Fight for Gunder’s Bight!</span>
<span class=impactfont16>E F</span>
<span class=ambrofont>UNCLE GLUSSOG'S TALENT PARADE</span>
```

To

```
<span class="cursivefont">Join the Fight for Gunder’s Bight!</span>
<span class="impactfont16">E F</span>
<span class="ambrofont">UNCLE GLUSSOG'S TALENT PARADE</span>
```

Comment: Tried that, but no luck. Also remember the other fonts seem to work without the quotes, but I tried it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Which Firefox version in your system or face this issue? Because Firefox less then "3.5" does not support external fonts.

Also one more problem. Firefox: Disabled by default, but can be enabled (need to set a flag to "true" to use WOFF2).

I have test your code in "snippet" with Firefox and Chrome working perfect.

Comment: Version 54.0.1 in windows, version 53.something on Android.               Using AMBROSIA.TTF, not WOFF.    I'll try condensing the page down to snippet and give that a go. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @user3229958 please refer this link: http://www.sunilboricha.com/font_demo/demo.html

I have update demo here with working font style.

Comment: @SunilBoricha Yes, i checked with your demo its working well in my local, i think issue with "snippet" its not consider that font.

Comment: @Minesh What did you mean 'its not consider that font'?  I'm prepared to believe I've done something wrong, perhaps there's something BETWEEN the 1st two spans and the last.  I'm puzzled that it SOMETIMES works for a single iteration!

Comment: just only check css for that font in sunilboricha demo link,, i take SunilBoricha code with  "snippet" but its not work, after that i checked with my local, its working fine .. so base on that i said that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming to the conclusion that it's the Ambrosia font, or perhaps my copy of the AMBROSIA.TTF file that's at fault.  I've substituted a different font for Ambrosia and it works every time.

I can't spend any more time on this - I have a publication deadline for Mythaxis - but I'm not closing the door. If anyone has a bright idea, I'd be interested.